# ios swift3, error says frame has no member size

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I don't know what the frame is exactly, but I can build

```
override public var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)
    let width = (buttonSize * starCount) + (spacing * (starCount-1))
    return CGSize(width: width, height: buttonSize)
}
```

But I can't build

```
class RatingControl: UIView {

// MARK: Properties 

let spacing = 5
let starCount = 5
let buttonSize = Int(frame.size.height)

.....
}
```

this code and error says "Value of type '(UIView) -> (CGRect) -> CGRect' has no member 'size'"

Why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't access `frame` property before self is initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you haven't declared the `frame` variable in some method.
Or better, as I see, that you extend UIView, you should use something like:

```
let buttonSize = Int(self.frame.size.height)
```

... or check what is that `frame` variable supposed to be, using

```
print(frame)
```

right before `let buttonSize ...` line